# Cannot seem to print a figure I imported from another file into pdf

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

I produce a plt plot (using Spyder) from a file called fedSentiChart.py as such

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
ax1.plot(Data.index, Data['Value'], color='m', linewidth=1.5)
```

Then in a separate file, I import this chart as such

```
from fedSentiChart import fig1
```

I want to put this chart in a pdf file as such

```
with PdfPages('/Users/mak/Test.pdf') as pdf:
    fig1
    pdf.savefig()
    plt.close()
```

But I get an error here:

```
ValueError: No figure None
```

Note: It works if I use this method

```
fig1.savefig('/Users/mak/Test.pdf')
```

But I want to produce a pdf with multiple pages.

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

I err "figured" it out...

```
with PdfPages('/Users/mak/Test.pdf') as pdf:
    pdf.savefig(fig1)
    plt.close()
```

This works.